# How do i save options changed by user interaction?

Tags: android, savechanges

I've asked a question like this before but the answers did not really help. If the user has changed the settings how do i save it so when the application is killed the changes are still saved. I have tried to use and save an int when the setting is changed, but when i go back, and then back to the page, the setting is back to normal. How do i save the setting with using shared Preferences or something?

Thank You

Comment: You should share the code that you're currently trying to use to store/retrieve the data.  Also take a look, if you haven't already, at the code/write-up here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref .   Edited to add another link:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Answer (score 2):

You want to use shared preferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

To store it:

```
private void putValue(String name, int value){
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", 0)
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sp.edit()

    prefEditor.putInt(name, value);
    prefEditor.commit()
}
```

to get it:

```
private void getValue(String name, int defaultValue){
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", 0)
    return sp.getInt("Name", defaultValue);
}
```

You can call in onPause

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    putValue("IntValue", value);
}
```

An then onResume()

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    value = getValue("IntValue", 0);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but what i'm doing is creating a tick if the item has been purchased. So when the item is clicked i set the alpha of the tick to 255 to show it has been purchased, however when i go back and then forward to it again its gone, sorry for the trouble

Comment: Well save the alpha value and then put the alpha value when you load it.